# iOS location based reminders not working accurately

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation

I created a location based reminder to notify me when I leave my house. However, the notification does not pop-up until I am about five miles away. What do I need to do to have the notification pop-up immediately after I leave the house? I am running iOS 9.

Answer (score 3):

When you get to the view where you can see the map and have selected `When I Leave` you can pinch and zoom to set the radius of where the notification will be triggered.[image: mapView pinch to zoom and change notification radius]